# Triggering Onitemclick grid view

Tags: android

I have a grid view set up with an onitemclickListener but when i click on an item it is not working can anybody please help me im struggeling to get this done

Main Activity

```
public class BahashActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {

        if(position == 0){
            Intent i = new Intent(BahashActivity.this, Age.class);
            BahashActivity.this.startActivity(i);

        }


    }


}
```

ImageAdapter

```
package your.age.namespace;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher };

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call?

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not useful. I dont know why, but when you implement the interface, and call 
"gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);", that does not work.'

The way to do it, is:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Proving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    });
```

I am sure, this will work fine.